# Data.table producing two values when one expected

Tags: r, data.table

The following set up:

```
x = data.table(id2 = c(0, 1))
y = data.table(id2 = c(0, 1), val=c(2,4))

x[id2==1][y, on = .(id2), val]
```

> [1] 2 4

Why am I not only getting one value as I should only match on the `id2 == 1` and get returned the `4`?

Comment: Sort of a typo, I guess you wanted `y[x[id2==1], on = .(id2), val]`

Answer (score 1):

This is because

```r
x[id2==1][y, on = .(id2), val]
```

is not the same as

```r
y[x[id2==1], on = .(id2), val]
```

It think this is easier to see without the final `[,val]` call.

## What you do

First, you filter `x`

```r
x[id2==1]
#   id2
# 1:   1
```

This reduces your data to one dimension. But, you make a **right outer join** that returns as *many rows* as there are keys in `y` which means 2. You cal is equivalent to the following `merge` function that is more explicit:

```r
merge(x,y, all.y = TRUE)
```

You have a good summary on joins in [that page](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/52230_5ae0d25125b544caab32f75f0360e775.html).